# Last observation for each company for each month (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, panel, xts

I have a dataframe z for which i have 8 million daily observations. For each company (measured with seriesid) I want the last value in the month if it is available, and else the value before (within the month) for both totalreturn and close price.

I have tried using `z[apply.monthly(z$date,max,by = z$seriesid)]`, however this returns only NAs. Other attempts with apply only returned me one date value (so not combined with the seriesids)

```
 date      company totalreturn   close seriesid 
 1: 2018-01-30 x   910.2214 133.375    55860     
 2: 2018-02-06 x   905.9561 132.750    55860     
 3: 2018-02-13 x   900.8377 132.000    55860     
 4: 2018-02-20 x   900.8377 132.000    55860     
 5: 2018-02-27 x   911.0745 133.500    55860     
 6: 2017-03-06 y   921.3112 135.000    55940    
 7: 2017-03-13 y   917.8990 134.500    55940
```

Ideally the dataset would be showns as

```
 date      company totalreturn   close seriesid 
 1: 2018-01-30 x   910.2214 133.375    55860        
 5: 2018-02-27 x   911.0745 133.500    55860         
 7: 2017-03-13 y   917.8990 134.500    55940
```

Containing one observation per company per month that is not NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `group_by` `seriesid` and year-month and select the last row which is non-NA for both `totalreturn` and `close`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(seriesid, month = format(date, "%Y%m")) %>%
  slice(which.max(cumsum(!is.na(totalreturn) & !is.na(close)))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-month)


#       date    company totalreturn close seriesid
#      <date>   <fct>         <dbl> <dbl>    <int>
#1    2018-01-30 x              910.  133.    55860
#2    2018-02-27 x              911.  134.    55860
#3    2017-03-13 y              918.  134.    55940
```

This is assuming your `date` column is of Date type or else you need to change it to Date class first.

---

Or using base R `ave` we can do

```
df1 <- df[complete.cases(df), ]

df1[unique(with(df1, ave(seq_along(date), seriesid, format(date, "%Y%m"), 
           FUN = function(x) tail(x, 1)))), ]
```